# Rails 4 - eager loading on dependent select causing error (Rails4/Active Admin)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, turbolinks

I have an Active panel with a dependent select i.e. the choice on the first dropdown select impacts what appears in the second drop-down.

All was working perfectly well a few months ago but i just realized yesterday it is not working any more.

I managed to find what cause the error: **if I remove the eager loading ("include"), then it works again.**

**NOT WORKING: (current version):**

```
@deal_subsectors = DealSector.find(params[:deal_sector_id],
   include: :deal_subsectors).dealsubsectors
```

I get this error (form chrome dev tools's Console)

```
GET http://localhost:3000/admin/deals/deal_subsectors_by_deal_sector?deal_sector_id=2 404 (Not Found)    
send @ jquery.js?body=1:9660    
jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery.js?body=1:9211    
jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js?body=1:9357    
jQuery.extend.getJSON @ jquery.js?body=1:9340    
update_deal_subsector @ active_admin.js?body=1:19    
(anonymous function) @ active_admin.js?body=1:12    
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?body=1:4666    
elemData.handle @ jquery.js?body=1:4334    
ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:632
```

**WORKING, when I remove "include" / eager loading :**

```
@deal_subsectors = DealSector.find(params[:deal_sector_id]).deal_subsectors
```

It works perfecty in that case.

But I really want to eager load deal subsectors so I wonder what is causing this error, what has changed since it was working. I have a few assumptions but can't find the culprit.

- Did Rails 4 change the way I should use find(params[:id]..) or the way i should use eager loading
- did active Admin change the way it handles eager loading: maybe it only works on index and not on edit pages...
- did turbolinks now on Rails 4 change the way i must eager load?

**Here's the code:**

**- on Active Admin**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Deal do

# controller for the multi-select sector/subsector in the form
# does 2 things at same time: creates method and automatically defines the route of the method defined in controller
    if params[:deal_sector_id] # pass the id
      @deal_subsectors = DealSector.find(params[:deal_sector_id], include: :deal_subsectors).dealsubsectors
    else
      @deal_subsectors = []
    end

    render json: @deal_subsectors
  end   

end
```

**- the form with the 2 dependent selects**

```
form do |f|

f.inputs "Client" do


      f.input :deal_sector_id,
        :label      => "Select industry:",
        :as         => :select,
        :prompt     => true,
        :collection => DealSector.order("name").all.to_a
      f.input :deal_subsector_id,
        :label      => "Select subindustry:",
        :as         => :select,
        :prompt     => true,
        :collection => DealSubsector.order("name").all.to_a        
    end

end
```

**- the javascript powering it:**

```
        // for edit page
        var deal_subsector = { };

       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#deal_deal_sector_id').change(function() {
            update_deal_subsector();
         });
       });

       function update_deal_subsector() {
           deal_sector_id = $('#deal_deal_sector_id').val(); //get the value of sector id
           url = '/admin/deals/deal_subsectors_by_deal_sector?deal_sector_id=' + deal_sector_id; //make a query to the url passing the deal sector id as a parameter
          $.getJSON(url, function(deal_subsectors) {
              console.log(deal_subsectors);
                  $('#deal_deal_subsector_id').html("") //just blanks the id, blank it before populating it again if sector changes
              for( i = 0; i < deal_subsectors.length; i++) {
                 console.log(deal_subsectors[i]);
                 $('#deal_deal_subsector_id').append("<option value=" + deal_subsectors[i].id + ">" + deal_subsectors[i].name + "</option>")
      };
    }); //pass the url and function to get subsector ids and all we get is assigned to the variable subsector_id
  };

          // for index page (filters)
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#q_deal_sector_id').change(function() {
                 update_deal_subsector_filter();
              });
              });

          function update_deal_subsector_filter() {
               deal_sector_id = $('#q_deal_sector_id').val(); //get the value of sector id
               url = '/admin/deals/deal_subsectors_by_deal_sector?deal_sector_id=' + deal_sector_id; //make a query to the url passing the deal sector id as a parameter
               $.getJSON(url, function(deal_subsectors) {
                      console.log(deal_subsectors);
                $('#q_deal_subsector_id').html("") //just blanks the id, blank it before populating it again if sector changes
                 for( i = 0; i < deal_subsectors.length; i++) {
                     console.log(deal_subsectors[i]);
                     $('#q_deal_subsector_id').append("<option value=" + deal_subsectors[i].id + ">" + deal_subsectors[i].name + "</option>")
      };
    }); //pass the url and function to get subsector ids and all we get is assigned to the variable subsector_id
        };
```

**ADDED file**

```
class DealSector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :deal_subsectors
end

class DealSubsector < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to  :deal_sector,   :foreign_key => 'deal_sector_id'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4 comes with some changes with respect to eager load algorithm.
you can try the below code snippets in your case:

```
@deal_subsectors = DealSector.eager_load(:deal_subsectors).find(params[:deal_sector_id]).dealsubsectors
```

or

```
@deal_subsectors = DealSector.includes(:deal_subsectors).find(params[:deal_sector_id]).dealsubsectors
```

first one will fetch the data in single query but second one will make two query.

Comment: seems to work. just a question: is it normal that the speed of loading that I can see inside my terminal is higher with @deal_subsectors = DealSector.eager_load(:deal_subsectors).find(params[:deal_sector_id]).deal_subsectors than when I do NO eager loading (@deal_subsectors = DealSector.find(params[:deal_sector_id]).deal_subsectors ? As I don't have many subsectors (like less than 20 for the moment), maybe it's normal than eagerloading takes more time than without eagerloading. Would it be right to say it eagerload will pay off when I'll have many more subsectors ?

Comment: Yes @mathieu your thoughts are absolutely correct. Most of the time eager loading keep you off from the N+1 query trap, without eager loading you may be running 100 query to get 1 result instead of running 1 query to get 100 results. eager loading will always pay off, may be you could get one or two exceptions.
In your case eagerloading definitely reduce the query time and make your response fast. bigger no. of data you will have more benefit you get from eager loading.

Comment: tx for your further explanations

Answer (score 2):

When you call `ActiveRecord::find` – it means you are expecting to get a one, single model from the DB.
Then, you referring to this model and call `dealsubsectors` – I assume it's `has_many` relation to your model. It will produce 2 queries: first to fetch original `DealSelector`, second – all related `DealSubsectors`.
There's nothing you can optimise (unless you `dealsubsectors` is a custom method in your model, not the relation).

If you see that something hits your DB with queries – you have to look in another place. Say, your form – do you display only one Client per form? If not, it will iterate and fetch all DealSector and DealSubsector again for every new client. Try to provide more code.

Comment: yes it has a has_many relations. Well when you say there nothing you can optimize but I don't think that's true: i thought egaer loading wxas precisely meant to load the associated ressources in one call so that the query is more efficient. so here i want to eager load with game sector the associated subsectors. I will add some code on model relations. Tell me what other code you'd need.

Comment: Using this code there's no way you can use eager load:
`DealSector.find(params[:deal_sector_id]).deal_subsectors` – you can run it from the console `(rails c)` and see the queries. It will fire 2 queries: to find `DealSector` and to fetch `DealSubsectors`. You have to think about other places where you load some models – e.g. in your view.

Comment: of course. what I'm expecting with this question is not that to be told it does not work as is. i know that. What I'm expecting is rather how I can manage to eagerload deal subsectors. I know for a fact you can eagerload models on active admin with :includes but I need guidance and answers to help me do it with precise answers or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just fetch the all DealSubsector records for the given the `sector_id`?

```
DealSubsector.where(deal_sector_id: params[:deal_sector_id])
```

Comment: Yury thanks but I am not saying what I was using was not working. this works perfectly: @deal_subsectors = DealSector.find(params[:deal_sector_id]).deal_subsectors BUT I want to use eager loading.